# Is this a virus?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc-sense, htc-vivid

When I try and open the "Movies" application on my phone (HTC Vivid w/ Sense 3.6 and ICS), I'm given with this notification (see image):

[image: The possible virus]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Now I don't think this is legit, so what do you think? Is this a virus? And if it is (which i think it is), how can I go about removing it?

Comment: OP: I think you're jumping to wrong conclusions. Where did you download that from? If its not from Google Play, you will get that message as I've explained in my answer below!

Comment: OEM manufacturers tend to bundle apps with new handsets that are sitting there until you install them :)

Comment: Viruses don't exist on Android, and I haven't heard about one for any other platform either recently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rest assured, that is not a virus, its a warning dialog to make you aware that you may have the app install from outside of Google Play blocked. It is normal! :)

To proceed to check and confirm it is indeed unblocked...

Go into Settings > Security > Device Administration, tap on "Unknown sources", a dialog box appears, tap ok as that's a standard disclaimer, which is normal de-facto thing.

For GB, Menu > Settings > Applications, check "Unknown Sources" and again, similar dialog appears as a disclaimer.

Tap Ok to continue and back out of it.

Answer (score 5):

More likely that the movie App just wants to get installed. It's not uncommon that 3rd party software is installed this way.

Comment: The thing that worried me was that it was installed by default my the OEM, but if you say its ok, then I'll give it permissions